# Random function always returns same result, despite different seeds

Tags: cobol, gnucobol

I'm trying to create a random number generator (from which some random numbers will later be converted into an [A-Z] character). I've got the main part of the random generator working, but I constantly receive the same random result `0.6734141422`.

Another issue I'm facing: half the time my program compiles too fast. Since I'm using the current date in Milliseconds, having my program compile fast will mean the same seed is given to the `RANDOM` function. I've been thinking about simply adding a counter that will divide each seed by the counter before applying it to `RANDOM`. Would this suffice or are there any more elegant solutions?

Could someone explain to me why I always receive the same random result even though different seed values are applied? I get this result every time I execute the program.

I'm using the PerCobol compiler, which is complient with OpenCobol as far as I've read.

To sum up:

- How should I overcome the equal seedings?
- Why am I receiving the same random result with different seeds?

  ```
  000100 IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
  000200 PROGRAM-ID. RandomTest.

  ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.  

     DATA DIVISION.
     WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
     01 RANDOMRESULT PIC S9V9(10).

     01 WS-CURRENT-DATE-DATA.
      05 WS-CURRENT-DATE.
        10 WS-CURRENT-YEAR    PIC 9(04).
        10 WS-CURRENT-MONTH   PIC 9(02).
        10  WS-CURRENT-DAY    PIC 9(02).
      05  WS-CURRENT-TIME.
    10  WS-CURRENT-HOURS      PIC 9(02).
    10  WS-CURRENT-MINUTE     PIC 9(02).
    10  WS-CURRENT-SECOND     PIC 9(02).
    10  WS-CURRENT-MILLISECONDS   COMP-2.
  05  WS-DIFF-FROM-GMT        PIC S9(04).

     PROCEDURE DIVISION.
     PRGRM.

     PERFORM 4 TIMES
      MOVE FUNCTION CURRENT-DATE TO WS-CURRENT-DATE-DATA
      COMPUTE RANDOMRESULT = FUNCTION RANDOM (WS-CURRENT-MILLISECONDS)
      DISPLAY "Seed value: " WS-CURRENT-MILLISECONDS UPON SYSOUT
      DISPLAY "Random result: " RANDOMRESULT UPON SYSOUT
     END-PERFORM

     STOP RUN.
  ```

Sample output:

```
Seed value: 8.222829361429599E-67
Random result: 0.6734141422
Seed value: 8.964670591567083E-67
Random result: 0.6734141422
Seed value: 9.335591206635825E-67
Random result: 0.6734141422
Seed value: 9.335591206635825E-67
Random result: 0.6734141422
```

If you have a suggestion towards approaching my original problem (creating a random password consisting of alphanumeric characters), I'd be glad to hear it as well.

EDIT:
By omitting the seed both problems are fixed at once. More behind this conclusion can be found in the comments below. If someone has an explanation as to why a different seed still results in the same value, I'd be glad to hear it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your seed needs to be an integer, so you can't use COMP-2. The seed does not need to be a particular size, just an integer, and you can probably make it pretty big.

The time it takes your program to compile is nothing to do with anything.

You should specify the SEED on the first invocation of the function. After that, use zero. This will follow the "pseudo-random" sequence. You do not need to "seed" every time, so no need to worry about miliseconds.

You should always output your seed, so that you can re-produce the sequence later. Makes it tricky to use the time, so instead take a parameter or a single-record file containing the seed.

Answer (score 1):

From [this post](http://ibmmainframes.com/post-54359.html), seems like the `RANDOM` function needs to take a 32-bit integer as a seed. However, you are declaring `WS-CURRENT-MILLISECONDS` as a `COMP-2` float (in other languages, a 64-bit double).

I imagine that this either makes it an invalid argument for the seed and hence the default seed value of 0 is used, or only the first or last 32 bits of the double is used, so you are basically getting either [part of the mantissa or significand](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) that is the same for the numbers you are trying.

If the first thing is happening, try using 0 as the seed, I imagine you'll get the same output. In any case, you can try seeding with some different integers explicitly and seeing what happens.

Comment: I get which direction you're going and it's probably somewhere around that, but seed `0` doesn't return the same result. However, I just found out that I don't need a seed at all. The resources I've read always suggested that the first `RANDOM` call should have a seed, but it works just fine (and as intended with sidderent results) by simply leaving the seed away. Even with the same timestamp this will result in a different result. Thanks for thinking with me though!

Comment: `COMP-2` is a 64 bit float and `RANDOM` takes a 32 bit seed, so some other things may be happening. I updated my post.

Comment: The reason for inputting a seed is so you can test your code.  In other words, you get an expected sequence for a given seed.

Comment: But why do I get the same sequence with different seeds?

Comment: Because you are using an invalid seed, so it is like using no seed at all (as far as the FUNCTION is concerned). You give the repeated invalid seed multiple times, so it always starts from the same point, so you get four "identical" random numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some source code to generate random numbers hope this helps.

```
   IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
   PROGRAM-ID.  RANDGEN as "ConsoleApplication2.RANDGEN".
   AUTHOR.  Myron D Denson.
   DATE-COMPILED.
  * ************************************************************** 
  *  SUBROUTINE TO GENERATE RANDOM NUMBERS THAT ARE GREATER THAN
  *    ZERO AND LESS OR EQUAL TO THE RANDOM NUMBERS NEEDED WITH NO
  *    DUPLICATIONS.  (CALL "RANDGEN" USING RANDGEN-AREA.)
  *     
  *    FORMULA CYCLES THROUGH EVERY NUMBER OF 2X2 ONLY ONCE. 
  *    RANDOM-NUMBERS FROM 1 TO RANDOM-NUMBERS-NEEDED ARE CREATED 
  *    AND PASSED BACK TO YOU.
  *
  *  RULES TO USE RANDGEN:
  *
  *    RANDOM-NUMBERS-NEEDED > ZERO 
  *     
  *    COUNT-OF-ACCESSES MUST = ZERO FIRST TIME USED.
  *         
  *    RANDOM-NUMBER = ZERO, WILL BUILD A SEED FOR YOU
  *    WHEN COUNT-OF-ACCESSES IS ALSO = 0 
  *     
  *    RANDOM-NUMBER NOT = ZERO, WILL BE NEXT SEED FOR RANDGEN
  *    YOU CAN PASS RANDGEN YOUR OWN RANDOM-NUMBER SEED
  *     THE FIRST TIME YOU USE RANDGEN.
  *     
  *    BY PLACING A NUMBER IN RANDOM-NUMBER FIELD
  *      THAT FOLLOWES THESE SIMPLE RULES:
  *        IF COUNT-OF-ACCESSES = ZERO AND 
  *        RANDOM-NUMBER > ZERO. 
  *    
  *    YOU CAN PICK THE SEED OR YOU CAN LET RANDGEN BUILD A SEED FOR YOU.
  *
  *       IF YOU PICK A SEED < RANDON-NUMBERS-NEEDED IT WILL BECOME THE LAST
  *          RANDON-NUMBER YOU RECEIVE BACK.
  *       IF SEED > RANDON-NUMBERS-NEEDED LAST NUMBER COULD BE ANYTHING.         
  *     
  *      THAT FOLLOWES THESE SIMPLE RULES:
  *        IF COUNT-OF-ACCESSES = ZERO AND 
  *        RANDOM-NUMBER = ZERO AND 
  *        RANDOM-NUMBER-NEEDED > ZERO  
  *         
  *     TO INSURING A DIFFERENT PATTERN OF RANDOM NUMBERS
  *        A LOW-RANGE AND HIGH-RANGE IS USED TO BUILD
  *        RANDOM NUMBERS.
  *        COMPUTE LOW-RANGE =
  *             ((SECONDS + HOURS + MINUTES + MS) * 1753).           
  *        A HIGH-RANGE = RANDOM-NUMBERS-NEEDED + LOW-RANGE
  *        AFTER RANDOM-NUMBER-BUILT IS CREATED 
  *        AND IS BETWEEN LOW AND HIGH RANGE
  *        RANDUM-NUMBER = RANDOM-NUMBER-BUILT - LOW-RANGE
  *               
  * **************************************************************         
   ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
   INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
   FILE-CONTROL.
   DATA DIVISION.
   FILE SECTION.
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
   01  WORK-AREA.
       05  X2-POWER                     PIC 9      VALUE 2. 
       05  2X2                          PIC 9(12)  VALUE 2.
       05  RANDOM-NUMBER-BUILT          PIC 9(12)  COMP.
       05  FIRST-PART                   PIC 9(12)  COMP.
       05  NOT-USED-NUMBER              PIC 9(12)  COMP.
       05  LOW-RANGE                    PIC 9(12)  VALUE ZERO.
       05  HIGH-RANGE                   PIC 9(12)  VALUE ZERO.
       05  YOU-PROVIDE-SEED             PIC X      VALUE SPACE.
       05  RUN-AGAIN                    PIC X      VALUE SPACE.
       05  PAUSE-FOR-A-SECOND           PIC X      VALUE SPACE.   
   01  SEED-TIME.
       05  HOURS                        PIC 99.
       05  MINUTES                      PIC 99.
       05  SECONDS                      PIC 99.
       05  MS                           PIC 99. 
  *
  * LINKAGE SECTION.
  *  Not used during testing  
   01  RANDGEN-AREA.
       05  COUNT-OF-ACCESSES            PIC 9(12) VALUE ZERO.
       05  RANDOM-NUMBERS-NEEDED        PIC 9(12) VALUE ZERO.
       05  RANDOM-NUMBER                PIC 9(12) VALUE ZERO.
       05  RANDOM-MSG                   PIC X(60) VALUE SPACE.
  *    
  * PROCEDURE DIVISION USING RANDGEN-AREA.
  * Not used during testing 
  *  
   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
   100-RANDGEN-EDIT-HOUSEKEEPING.
       MOVE SPACE TO RANDOM-MSG. 
       IF RANDOM-NUMBERS-NEEDED = ZERO
         DISPLAY 'RANDOM-NUMBERS-NEEDED ' NO ADVANCING
         ACCEPT RANDOM-NUMBERS-NEEDED.
       IF RANDOM-NUMBERS-NEEDED NOT NUMERIC 
         MOVE 'RANDOM-NUMBERS-NEEDED NOT NUMERIC' TO RANDOM-MSG
           GO TO 900-EXIT-RANDGEN.
       IF RANDOM-NUMBERS-NEEDED = ZERO
         MOVE 'RANDOM-NUMBERS-NEEDED = ZERO' TO RANDOM-MSG
           GO TO 900-EXIT-RANDGEN.
       IF COUNT-OF-ACCESSES NOT NUMERIC
         MOVE 'COUNT-OF-ACCESSES NOT NUMERIC' TO RANDOM-MSG
           GO TO 900-EXIT-RANDGEN.
       IF COUNT-OF-ACCESSES GREATER THAN RANDOM-NUMBERS-NEEDED
         MOVE 'COUNT-OF-ACCESSES > THAT RANDOM-NUMBERS-NEEDED' TO RANDOM-MSG
           GO TO 900-EXIT-RANDGEN.
       IF YOU-PROVIDE-SEED = SPACE AND RANDOM-NUMBER = ZERO
         DISPLAY 'DO YOU WANT TO PROVIDE SEED  Y OR N: '
           NO ADVANCING
           ACCEPT YOU-PROVIDE-SEED.  
       IF RANDOM-NUMBER = ZERO AND
          (YOU-PROVIDE-SEED = 'Y' OR 'y')
         DISPLAY 'ENTER SEED ' NO ADVANCING
         ACCEPT RANDOM-NUMBER. 
       IF RANDOM-NUMBER NOT NUMERIC
         MOVE 'RANDOM-NUMBER NOT NUMERIC' TO RANDOM-MSG
         GO TO 900-EXIT-RANDGEN.
   200-RANDGEN-DATA-HOUSEKEEPING.      
       MOVE FUNCTION CURRENT-DATE (9:8) TO SEED-TIME.
       IF COUNT-OF-ACCESSES = ZERO
         COMPUTE LOW-RANGE =
                ((SECONDS + HOURS + MINUTES + MS) * 1753).
       COMPUTE RANDOM-NUMBER-BUILT = RANDOM-NUMBER + LOW-RANGE.  
       COMPUTE HIGH-RANGE = RANDOM-NUMBERS-NEEDED + LOW-RANGE.
       MOVE X2-POWER TO 2X2.             
   300-SET-2X2-DIVISOR.
       IF 2X2 < (HIGH-RANGE + 1) 
          COMPUTE 2X2 = 2X2 * X2-POWER
           GO TO 300-SET-2X2-DIVISOR.    
  * *********************************************************         
  *  IF FIRST TIME THROUGH AND YOU WANT TO BUILD A SEED.    *
  * ********************************************************* 
       IF COUNT-OF-ACCESSES = ZERO AND RANDOM-NUMBER = ZERO
          COMPUTE RANDOM-NUMBER-BUILT =
                ((SECONDS + HOURS + MINUTES + MS) + HIGH-RANGE).
  * *********************************************     
  *    END OF BUILDING A SEED IF YOU WANTED TO  * 
  * ********************************************* 
  * *******************************************************
  * THE NEXT 4 LINE OF CODE ARE FOR TESTING  ON CONSOLE   *  
  * *******************************************************            
  *    IF COUNT-OF-ACCESSES = ZERO        
  *      DISPLAY 'SEED TIME ' SEED-TIME 
  *            ' RANDOM-NUMBER-BUILT ' RANDOM-NUMBER-BUILT 
  *            ' LOW-RANGE  ' LOW-RANGE.          
  * ***************************************************
  * THIS PROCESS IS WHERE THE RANDOM-NUMBER IS BUILT  *  
  * ***************************************************   
   400-RANDGEN-FORMULA.
       COMPUTE FIRST-PART = (5 * RANDOM-NUMBER-BUILT) + 7.
       DIVIDE FIRST-PART BY 2X2 GIVING NOT-USED-NUMBER 
         REMAINDER RANDOM-NUMBER-BUILT. 
       IF RANDOM-NUMBER-BUILT > LOW-RANGE AND
          RANDOM-NUMBER-BUILT < (HIGH-RANGE + 1)
         GO TO 600-RANDGEN-CLEANUP.
       GO TO 400-RANDGEN-FORMULA.
  * *********************************************     
  *    GOOD RANDOM NUMBER HAS BEEN BUILT        *               
  * *********************************************
   600-RANDGEN-CLEANUP.
       ADD 1 TO COUNT-OF-ACCESSES.
       COMPUTE RANDOM-NUMBER = 
            RANDOM-NUMBER-BUILT - LOW-RANGE. 
  * *******************************************************
  * THE NEXT 3 LINE OF CODE ARE FOR TESTING  ON CONSOLE   *  
  * *******************************************************
       DISPLAY RANDOM-NUMBER.
       IF COUNT-OF-ACCESSES < RANDOM-NUMBERS-NEEDED
        GO TO 100-RANDGEN-EDIT-HOUSEKEEPING.     
   900-EXIT-RANDGEN.
       IF RANDOM-MSG NOT = SPACE
        DISPLAY 'RANDOM-MSG: ' RANDOM-MSG.
        MOVE ZERO TO COUNT-OF-ACCESSES RANDOM-NUMBERS-NEEDED RANDOM-NUMBER. 
        MOVE SPACE TO YOU-PROVIDE-SEED RUN-AGAIN.
       DISPLAY 'RUN AGAIN Y OR N '
         NO ADVANCING.
       ACCEPT RUN-AGAIN.
       IF (RUN-AGAIN = 'Y' OR 'y')
         GO TO 100-RANDGEN-EDIT-HOUSEKEEPING.
       ACCEPT PAUSE-FOR-A-SECOND.
       GOBACK.
```

Comment: If no number can be repeated, I don't think it even counts as pseudo-random, let alone random. Program been around a while? Surely the `CALL`ing program need not have a `LINKAGE SECTION` at all.

Comment: It is meant to be used for drawing as though you where drawing numbers from a hat.  Where you can have only one winner.  The program is parts and pieces from a much larger program. sorry for the extra parts, They should be comments in the code. Code is from 40 year old mainframe program.